# How to pass a Relation as a subquery in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

The example below works in Rails 3 but fails in Rails 4.

The reason is that the `Relation` returned by accessing the association now uses actual database parameter rather than interpolating the "owning" id.

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
end


class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
end


b = Blog.first # provided something exists of course
query = Post.where(id: b.posts.where("'complicated query' = ''")); 1 # just to avoid printing in console

puts query.to_sql

# SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."id" IN (SELECT "posts"."id" FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."blog_id" = $1 AND ('complicated query' = ''))


query.to_a

# raises the error:
# PG::UndefinedParameter: ERROR:  there is no parameter $1
# LINE 1: ...M "posts"  WHERE "posts"."blog_id" = $1 AND 
#                                                 ^
```

Note the `$1` parameter in the subquery which is obviously not provided from the main query (thus the error).

So the question is how can we do the same thing in Rails 4 now (preferably with minimal changes)?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

This actually isn't a breaking change in Rails 4. It should still works as expected.

It is `squeel` gem that breaks it https://github.com/ernie/squeel/issues/272